# Java: what about my classOf and newArray?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010924/java-how-to-implement-toarray-for-collection), I wondered about how to implement `Collection#toArray(T[] array)` properly. I was mostly annoyed that `array.getClass().getComponentType()` is of type `Class<?>` and not `Class<? extends T>` as I would have expected.

Therefore, I coded these three functions:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") static <T> Class<? extends T> classOf(T obj) {
    return (Class<? extends T>) obj.getClass();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") static <T> Class<? extends T> classOf(T[] array) {
    return (Class<? extends T>) array.getClass().getComponentType();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") static <T> T[] newArray(Class<T> clazz, int size) {
    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```

And then, my `toArray` implementation looks like:

```
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] array) { 
        int size = size();
        if (array.length < size) { 
            array = newArray(classOf(array), size);
        } else if (array.length > size) {
            array[size] = null;
        }

        int i = 0;
        for (E e : this) {
            array[i] = classOf(array).cast(e);
            i++;
        }
        return array;
    }
```

What I wonder about now is:

Are these 3 helper functions always safe? Esp., is the cast always safe?

Why aren't these functions already in Java?

Also see this very related questions: [`T obj` for a generic type `T`. The type of `obj.getClass()` is `Class<?>` and not `Class<? extends T>`. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010957/java-t-obj-type-of-obj-getclass-is-class-and-not-class-extends-t-why)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty much OK, but you might consider using `java.util.Arrays.copyOf` to simplify your life.